# Clearing the data entered in the PredicatEditor

Tags: cocoa, nspredicateeditor

I have a PredicateEditor with lot of rows in it.When you enter any value in the predicate row and if you want to clear all the data that was present What exactly has to be done.?

I tried by just traversing the subViews and setting null values . it actually clears the data from the view but not from the predicate.

Answer (score 1):

NSPredicateEditor is an NSRulesEditor. Call -removeRowsAtIndexes:includeSubrows: to remove the desired rules.

Comment: Thanks, i tried this, But what i really need is to clear the data not the rules.

Comment: How about -reloadCriteria? "You can use this method to indicate that the available criteria may have changed and should be refetched from the delegate and the popups recalculated."